# Почему функция JS не работает?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Car</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
</head>

<body>

    <button id='start-car'>Start</button>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>


</html>



JS:

function carStartListener() {
    alert('button clicked');
}


var startButton= document.getElementById("start-car");
startButton.addEventListener("click",carStartListener);
```

Comment: Как вы тестировали функцию? Работает нормально. Вы можете дважды проверить структуру файла и именование на вашем компьютере.

Comment: запускал в Google но нечего не происходило, хоть и другие, слишком простые команды работают, только вот это функция никак не запускаеться

Answer (score 1):

Не понятно что у Вас но тут работает

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Car</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
</head>

<body>

    <button id='start-car'>Start</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    function carStartListener() {
        alert('button clicked');
    }


    var startButton= document.getElementById("start-car");
    startButton.addEventListener("click",carStartListener);

    </script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: хм... здесь все работает, но Google почему то не выполняет ее, не знаете почему так может быть?

Comment: Где не выполняет. Покажите или ещё как

Comment: var startButton= document.getElementById("start-car");
    startButton.addEventListener("click",carStartListener);
вот это, пишет что carStartListener не определен

Comment: конечно странно однако\